# Match a string in multiple words

Tags: string, algorithm, substring

I have found many solutions on how to match multiple patterns in string, but didn't find how to match a single string in many words.

The best way so far that I know is to use KMP algorithm for each of the words, but this isn't  so efficient(complexity = sum of words length), so I'm looking for some better algorithm to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have fundamentally misunderstood the problem.  You can easily decompose the problem into finding all occurrences of a string in a word.  This is done by combining each individual string into one large string (or word).  Then you can iterate over this larger string once and use an efficient algorithm such as KMP or a regex (wouldn't necessarily recommend using the regex though).  An example to show what I mean:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String first = "abc";  
    String second = "def";  
    String third = "xyz";  
    stringList.add(first);  
    stringList.add(second);  
    stringList.add(third);  

for(String string : stringList)  
{  
    kmp(string);  
}
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();  
stringList.add("abcdefxyz");  
for(String string : stringList)  
{  
   kmp(string);   
}
```

As Kevin pointed out in the comments the use of a delimiter here would prevent incorrect results from being generated.

Comment: But what about this: the word "cat" can't be found in either "basic" or "atom"; but it can be found in the combined string "basicatom". So your two code samples are not strictly equivalent.

Comment: @Kevin sure I will concede that point, adding a delimiter would resolve that issue

Comment: The  that I found so far is following:

Comment: The optimization that I found so far is following: Sorting all strings according to length (bigger go first). Trying to find if string at position n is substring of strings at  positions n-1. This will be the precompute step. Then when I have to search a string in my diction I'll start from he end. If my string is substring of some string in array, let's call this string S, then my string will be substring of all string in array which have S as their substring. But I just curious if there is a better way.